# Analogous of $\int 1.999 x^{0.999} \mathrm dx \approx x^2$ for $\int e^{-x^2} \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

So everyone knows that $\int e^{-x^2} \mathrm dx$ can not be evaluated in terms of elementary functions. So is there a way to have something approximate? for example although the following is not well defined yet it is not too hard to allow :

$\int 1.999 x^{0.999} \mathrm dx \approx x^2$ but in this case $1.999 x^{0.999}$ can be integrated in terms of elementary functions, but if it was not possible, we could have replaced it with $2x$.

My question is can we do something similar for $e^{-x^2} $ or other functions that have no elementary integrals and substitute in something that is **close enough** to the original function that has an integral in terms of elementary functions?

By "close enough" I have no formalised definition to say what I mean, please mention things that can make 'close enough' in this context more meaningful.

Comment: You can expand the power series for $e^{-x^2}$ to an arbitrarily large number of terms.

Comment: @Potato : Yes, but also could have done that for $1.999x^{0.999}$, but instead using $x$ somehow seemed preferable. can we swap $e^{-x^2}$ with some other function ( even if that other function depended on the interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some possibilities, but they are valid only in a limited range of values for $x$. The same holds for your $1.999x^{0.9999}$ actually :-)

Consider the following
$$
D(\frac1{2x}e^{-x^2})=\frac{-2x}{2x}e^{-x^2}-\frac1{2x^2}e^{-x^2}=-e^{-x^2}(1+\frac1{2x^2}).
$$
So for very large $x$ the derivative of $-e^{-x^2}/(2x)$ is close to $e^{-x^2}$. You can repeat the dose and use
$$
D\left(e^{-x^2}(-\frac1{2x}+\frac1{4x^3})\right)=e^{-x^2}(1+\frac3{4x^4})
$$
or go even further.

These approximations are useful only for relatively large values of $x$, e.g. estimating the tail probability of a normal random variable having a value, say $+10$SD or above. For smaller values of $x$ undoubtedly other types of tricks work better, but I'm not an expert.